# C++, Protobuf, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers

I download protobuf-21.2 and executed following instructions to install protobuf:

```
./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make check && sudo make install
```

and I use a following example to make practice:

test.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Test {
        optional string name =1;
        optional int32 age = 2;
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test.pb.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Test pro_t;
    pro_t.set_age(3);
    cout<<pro_t.age();
    return 0;
}
```

and run the command to compile proto file:

```
protoc -I=./ --cpp_out=./ ./test.proto
```

run the command to complie cpp file:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp test.pb.cc -lprotobuf -I /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/ -L /usr/local/lib -std=c++11
```

but when I complie cpp ,I got a problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata::~InternalMetadata()", referenced from:
      google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite() in test-0f87f5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: did you download/install an arm build of protobuf? Look earlier in the build log for warnings about incompatible libraries

Comment: The error message sounds like the library included could be of different version than the headers found during compilation. Note that the generated files have `google/protobuf` at the beginning of the included file name, so `-I /usr/local/include` might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Changed build type of Debug to Release solved my problem.